# How to make a new button on a button click in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am new to Android Studio. I have a two buttons - Button1 and Button2. When I click on Button1, a few more buttons - Button1A and Button1B should show up between Button1 and Button2. When I click on Button1 again (or unclick), those buttons (Button1A and Button1B) should go away.

My problem is figuring out the overall logistics: how should those buttons be generated and how to keep the format?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

In activity_main.xml, I just have Button1 and Button2.

Java code (MainActivity):

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);

       button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               //create two more buttons 
           }
       });
    }
}
```

[A sketch of what the screen should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9L3N.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add all those buttons in the xml file in the positions where you want them to be. And based on your need make

```
buttonName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to make button invisible

Or

```
buttonName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to make button visible.

Look here for more info https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility